# Linux run on ARM Cortex-M4 MCU

Tags: linux, arm, microcontroller

I own [NUCLEO-F334R8](http://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f334r8.html) board, based on [STM32F334R8](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/d1/cd/3d/18/a2/2c/4e/d0/DM00097745.pdf/files/DM00097745.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00097745.pdf) ARM Cortex-M4 microcontroller.

It's 72MHz board without MMU, 64KB flash, 12KB RAM.

I can connect it with **external** flash and RAM.

[image: Cortex-M4] [image: ucLinux]

[ucLinux](http://www.uclinux.org/) is Linux version for microcontrollers.

How i can install it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

The STM32F334 lacks a FSMC (flexible static memory controller) peripheral, so it cannot use external RAM. (It may be possible to *connect* a memory chip, but it cannot be made to appear in the MCU's address space.) The 12 KB of embedded SRAM is insufficient to run µCLinux.